# What is wrong with my question about Firefox opening two tabs for a link?

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes

I would like to understand what is wrong with this question:

*[window.open with _blank opens two tabs in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57579926/window-open-with-blank-opens-2-tabs-in-firefox)*

- I have provided the code
- I have provided a jsfiddle
- I have provided an **animated GIF image** displaying what happens

Being down-rated, without being told why, is extremely frustrating on sites like Stack Overflow. I've been with SO for nearly 9 years. I used to find it really useful. But now it seems that everyone of my questions gets initially downvoted or closed. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted your question, but this: "I avoid asking questions there until it is my final option." should actually be the default behavior of every user. Asking a question on SO is never the first thing to do, it's the last thing to do when you have exhausted your other options. That's what downvotes can mean: not enough prior research.

Comment: That said, Jordan, the entire network is predicated on the rating system; it's how we know what is good, and what isn't.  It's why you find it really useful.  Without that, you wouldn't have been able to use it for nearly nine years.

Comment: I migrated this here because it is about an issue on Stack Overflow but also because I think that your second paragraph is your real question and MSO is the best place to have that answered. I'm sorry that you're frustrated. Your experience is common to many on SO and on the network. Asking questions is hard and we can do better to help improve that experience - and we are in the process of improving that. But if you need help improving a question, there's room to ask for help on MSO or in chat.

Comment: FYI: I've rewritten this question to focus on the actual *question* part that @Catija talks about, removing some of the side commentary in the process.

Comment: see also: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/839601)

Comment: @Shog9 Re: the edit, isn't a 'what's wrong with my question' Meta question a discussion thing rather than a support thing?

Comment: Could be either; I tend to think of them more as support questions, but YMMV @TylerH

Comment: Same. A user comes to us with a problem regarding a specific question or set of questions is support. There may be a general sentiment behind it, but overall it’s to get support for the specific issues they’re having. That’s also why I’m ok with closing some as duplicates but only so long as we also address their specific support issue too.

Comment: @fbueckert, I'm find with a rating system in general. I just don't like being rated without knowing why.

Comment: Good thing it's not you we're rating, then, Jordan. It's the content you're posting that's getting rated. As for requiring comments with downvotes...that's never going to happen. It's probably one of the most common requests on Meta.

Answer (score 14):

> Being down-rated without being told why is extremely frustrating on sites like stackoverflow. I've been with SO for nearly 9 years. I used to find it really useful. But now everyone of my questions gets initially down-voted or closed.

In the last *four* years you have two questions that are negatively scored (including the one you linked above), and 11 that are *not* negatively scored. This doesn't sound like "everyone of my questions gets initially down-voted or closed" to me, or even close. Likewise, you've asked a *lot* of questions (276! https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A443602+is%3Aq) -- I would not expect to have a flawless record across that many questions... you're bound to incur a few downvotes here and there.

> Tell me, what is wrong with this question? I have provided a jsfiddle. I have provided an animated gif displaying what happens.

I don't know for sure why the two users who downvoted your question did so, but it *could* be because they couldn't reproduce the issue themselves (though they didn't both also vote to close as no-repro... maybe they don't have 3k reputation). I know *I* couldn't reproduce the issue, and even commented as such on your post when I saw it (I haven't yet voted up or down on the question).

Comment: There were actually 4 users who downvoted. The question is at +2/-4

Comment: @BDL At the time I saw the question it was at 0/-2. I'm guessing the additional 4 votes came from the Meta Effect.

Comment: FYI: I've rewritten this question to focus on the actual *question* part, removing some of the side commentary in the process.

Comment: I respect you removing the side commentary. I am venting, I was very frustrated. I'm an expert developer. I don't want to have to be an expert stackexchanger as well. I just want a place to ask a question. I do know how to google search. And I do my research before I ask a question. Will my question even be seen if it is down voted? If so, what on earth is the point of the down vote? If not, likewise.

Comment: @Jordan Questions are removed from the front page if they reach a score of -3. Yours is current not at that so it will still be seen. Likewise, people browsing by specific/followed tags or searching using specific search queries will still see your post show up in those question lists. The point of a downvote is to convey that someone finds the question unclear, low effort, or low quality (though because it's just a click, a lot of people use them for other reasons too, unfortunately).

Comment: @Jordan By the way, there is another way to practically ensure you get attention on a question: raise a bounty. Regardless of question score, a question with an active bounty appears on the bounty tab's question list, rising closer to the top each day the question draws closer to the bounty's closure date. You can offer up to 500 reputation for an answer if it is something you really need help with, and even the minimum 50 rep bounty will usually entice a lot of people to give a question a second look.